# $date->setDate doesn't work

Tags: php, datetime

I need to change the timezone of a datetime string.

This is my code:

```
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
    $date->setDate('2012-04-21');
    $date->setTime('12:42:59');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The first echo displays: "2016-01-12 10:40:03"

The setDate functions does no effect.

Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: You could always look into using createFromFormat if you are loading the date and time dynamically see PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php) would have helped you

The arguments for `setDate()` are:

```
setDate ( int $year , int $month , int $day )
```

not a date string

similarly with the arguments for `setTime()`

Comment: awkward, Thanks for help

Comment: @nagazi - If this answer helped, please let other's know by accepting it (click the tick to the left).  http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

php DateTime setDate [function description](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php). try

```
$date->setDate(2012, 04, 21);
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP setDate Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php)

`setDate ( int $year , int $month , int $day )`

[PHP setTime Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php)

`setTime ( int $hour , int $minute , int $second )`

```
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
    $date->setDate(2012,04,21);
    $date->setTime(12,42,59);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo '<br/>';
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

See Eval Demo: https://3v4l.org/14mqi